# How to write a binary file directly from Databricks (PySpark) to Azure DataLake?

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to writing some binary data into a file directly to ADLS from Databricks. Basically, I'm fetching the content of a docx file from Salesforce and want it to store the content of it into ADLS. I'm using PySpark.

**Here is my first try:**

```
file_path = "adl://<something>.azuredatalakestore.net/<...folders...>/Report.docx"
data = request.content # fetched binary data 

with open(file_path, "wb") as file:
    file.write(data)
```

**And the error I get is:**

```
with open(file_path, "wb") as file:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'adl://<something>.azuredatalakestore.net/<...folders...>/Report.docx'
```

**Now, the second try:**

```
file_path = "adl://<something>.azuredatalakestore.net/<...folders...>/Report.docx"
data = request.content

dbutils.fs.put(file_path, data, True)
```

**Again, an error:**

```
dbutils.fs.put(file_path, data, True)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00...
```

But, when I'm trying to write some normal unicode string using dbutils.fs.put(), it's working fine.

```
dbutils.fs.put(file_path, "abcd", True)

# adl://<something>.azuredatalakestore.net/<...folders...>/Report.docx
# Wrote 4 bytes.
```

**I've also used base64, but not getting the desired result.**

```
dbutils.fs.put(file_path, base64.b64encode(data).decode('utf-8'), True)
```

It's saving the file, but the file is becoming **unreadable**.

Can anyone please help me to complete my task??

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an Azure DataLake Storage Gen2 account and a container.
Note down the Account name, Container name, and Account key
[image]
[image]

Mount the ADLS to Databricks using the mounting script:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point = "/mnt/io89765",
    extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net":"<storage-account-Access key>"})
```

[image]

Install the azure-storage-file-datalake package in Databricks cluster.
You can run  the following command:

```
   %pip install azure-storage-file-datalake
```

[image]

Use the below command to list your mounted file.

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/io243")
```

[image]

Read the file path and read in binary format

```
docx_file_path = "/dbfs/mnt/io243/docx.docx"

with open(docx_file_path, "rb") as f:
  binary_data = f.read()
```

Writing the file to Dataframe:

```
    from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, BinaryType


schema = StructType([StructField("data", BinaryType())])
df = spark.createDataFrame([(binary_data,)], schema=schema)
```

display the binary format:

```
df.display()
```

[image]

Comment: mounts are deprecated & not recommended anymore

Answer (score 0):

Just use `dbutils.fs` commands ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#file-system-utility-dbutilsfs)) to copy the file written to the local disk. With something like this:

```py
file_path = "adl://<something>.azuredatalakestore.net/<...folders...>/Report.docx"
data = request.content # fetched binary data 
tmp_path = "/tmp/tmp.file"

with open(tmp_path, "wb") as file:
    file.write(data)

dbutils.fs.cp(f"file:{tmp_path}", file_path)
```

The last command (or use `dbutils.fs.mv`) will use the configured credentials to access ADLS.